How can I add custom converters to Npgsql EF Core (8) traditional POCO mapping?
I need to use traditional POCO mapping to jsonb with PostgreSQL and EF Core (.net 8). The structure of those classes in fairly complex and I don't need to query them with Linq to EF. But I need to be able to properly serialize and deserialize them. Serialization kinda works by default with System.Text.Json that Npgsql is using, but for deserialization I definitely need the JsonConverters.
But I don't know how to register them with the Npgsql driver.
[Update]
I might have found my answer here: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/5562
NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder has an extension method ConfigureJsonOptions.

So is this still a question?

No, but still a legit question, that others might find useful.

Then please add an answer, showing how you applied the code in the link. If you accept the answer later it's clear that the question has come to a conclusion.
